# What is greater : O(mn) OR O((m^2)/n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, runtime, big-o, time-complexity

I have an algorithm with this order:
**O((m^2)/n) + O(mn)**

I want to know: Is it equal to **O(mn)**?

**O((m^2)/n) > O(mn)** OR **O((m^2)/n) < O(mn)** ???

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because ... **math**

Comment: I think it can be equal only if `m=n`

Comment: Is there some input definition for m and n. For example, is m a substring or subset of n or something?

Comment: We have some arrays. m is number of arrays and n is maximum length of each array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should just say the complexity is `O(m^2/n + mn)`.

Let's see when they're equal:

```
(m^2)/n = mn
m^2 = m(n^2)
m = n^2
```

So, if `m = n^2`, they are equal,
when `m > n^2`, `m^2/n` is dominant,
when `m < n^2`, `mn` is dominant.

Thus neither is always greater than the other, thus we can't cancel out either.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensionally speaking, they cannot be compared. If unit of m and n is same say UNIT

But (m^2)/n is measured in UNIT and mn in UNIT^2 or UNIT-Squared.

```
(m^2)/n < mn
```

if you take `m = n`, then `m^2/n` will be `n`.

It means m and n are of same order (or of same magnitude), then complexity is `O(mn)`.

If the order of m and n are different,

```
 if m^2 < n, then it will be O(mn)
 if m^2 > n, then it will be O(m^2/n)
```

Comment: Your first claim, that `if m^2 <= n then it will be O(mn)` is true. You did definitely prove it. However your second claim that `if m^2 > n, then it will be O(m^2/n)` is *not* true. It is possible for m^2 to be greater than n and yet m*n still be greater than m^2/n. An easy counterexample is m = 3 and n = 4. m*n = 12 and m^2 = 9 > n. m^2 / n = 9 / 4 which is less than m*n = 12 so m*n still dominates. See Dukeling's answer to see the tighter bounds.

Comment: @ShashankGupta: Please post an edit with the example. Thanks. I did not realize that.